# How can I get the reference of a List element?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the reference of one element out of a list?

I know how to reference a complete list to another list:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []

b = a

a[1] = 3

print (b) #b is now [1, 3, 3]
```

But how can I get the reference to one element?
For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []

b = a[1] 

a[1] = 3

print (b) #b is now 2, but I want the value 3 like it is in a[1]
```

Or is there another solution for this problem in python?

Comment: No, the behavior you are describing is not possible in Python.

Comment: Ok. Is there no other possility for two lists that points to the same values. But one list is only a subset of the other list.

Comment: Only if the values in the lists are mutable.

Comment: To bad. I want to generate two lists of classes.
One "global" list with a user class and another list with an article class.
Each article should have a "local" list of users, that are interested in this article. But this local list should only point to a subset of users of the "global" user list.

Comment: Python is an interpreted scripting language and the stuff that you are trying to do needs more "Compiled" type languages like C/C++ where you can reference memory locations using pointers. May be you are trying to use a programming language but don't know if this addresses your purpose?

Comment: If you're used to how variables work in languages like C/C++ you may find the way that they work in Python surprising &/or annoying at first. But if you adopt the Pythonic viewpoint you will gradually come to realise the beauty of it. You may be interested in what I said on this topic in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26731680/4014959) from a week or so ago. And also see the Ned Batchelder link in my comment to Adem Öztaş's answer below.

Comment: Yes I am more used to C/C++. I just discoverd Python for me as a nice language to get quick results and wanted to learn more about it by doing some little projects. Thank you all for your help! I will read your posted links. Hopefully I will get an idea how to solve my problem the Python-Way. :-)

Comment: It really sounds like you should have a user entry type (probably mutable, so each user is unique), which will let you refer to users from both global and article lists. If the global list should additionally be the master list of existing users, one solution might be [weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html).

Comment: @hagubear see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26945874/890242) below, Python variables are always references to objects, this has much to do with understanding the language you are using, and nothing with compiled v.s. scripted/interpreted (btw, Python is a compiled language, too, but that's a discussion for another day...)

Comment: @char0n You can do what you want, just not what you asked... :)  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, because integers are immutable, while list are mutable.

In `b = a[1]` you are actually assigning a new value to `b`

Demo:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> id(a)
38666560
>>> a += 2
>>> id(a)
38666512
```

You can like this,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a[1] = 3
>>> b
[1, 3, 3]
>>> a
[1, 3, 3]
>>> id(a)
140554771954576
>>> id(b)
140554771954576
```

[You can read this document.](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: Ok, I never heard something about "mutable" and "immutable". The integer values are just an example for my problem to point on elements in lists or do I have the same problem mit other types? Because actually I want to list classes and point with other lists to specific elements of this "class" list.

Comment: If you have never heard about "mutable" and "immutable" then you have a _major_ gap in your knowledge of how Python variables work. I suggest you look at Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (Ned is a regular here).

Comment: @PM2Ring it's very useful

Answer (score 2):

As jonrsharpe said, you can do what you want by using mutable elements in your list, eg make the list elements lists themselves.

For example

```
a = [[i] for i in xrange(5)]
print a

b = a[3]
print b[0]


a[3][0] = 42

print a
print b[0]


b[:] = [23]

print a
print b
```

**output**

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
3
[[0], [1], [2], [42], [4]]
42
[[0], [1], [2], [23], [4]]
[23]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is an object oriented language with first class functions. It doesn't deal with pointers in the way C does. List entries are not objects in themselves, so you'd need to hold both an item index and a reference to the container to do the sort of slot handling you describe. There are packages that do this, for instance [buffers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer), [memory views](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type), or numpy [ndarrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), but it requires a layer of indirection because an assignment of the form `foo = something` will bind the name foo, not modify what foo used to refer to.

Here is one example of such an indirection class:

```
class Indirect(object):
    def __init__(self, container, item):
        self.container = container
        self.item = item
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.container[self.item]
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self.container[self.item] = value

l = [1,2,3]
ref = Indirect(l, 1)
ref.value = 5
print(l)
```

The first class function support means you can also create a function on the fly for the specific task you need:

```
l = [1,2,3]
def callwith5(func):    # doesn't know what func does
    return func(5)
setanitem = lambda i: l[1]=i    # creates a new function
callwith5(setanitem)
print(l)
```

Another way to express this difference is that Python doesn't really have `lvalue` in C terminology; we just have a few syntactic extensions that translate assignment statements into varying calls:

```
a = 1      # if a is global:  setitem(globals(), 'a', 1)
a = 1      # otherwise:       setitem(locals(), 'a', 1)
foo.a = 1  # setattr(foo, 'a', 1)  => foo.__setattr__('a', 1)
l[1] = 5   # setitem(l, 1, 5)      => l.__setitem__(1, 5)
```

Many of them are optimized such that there is no lookup of setitem, setattr etc, and those in turn have a set of rules that refer to specific methods like `__setitem__` and `__setattr__`, but in the end the rule is that everything is accessed via some object, with the roots being the module dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, everything is an object, including numbers. Numbers are *immutable* objects, and they exist only once. In other words in the above example, `a` does *not* hold the value two, it holds the reference to the `Number` object that represents the integer 2. This can be verified easily:

```
a = 2 # reference to the object that represents integer 2
print type(2), type(a), isinstance(2, Number), isinstance(a, Number)
=> <type 'int'> <type 'int'> True True
```

Similarly this is shown by looking at the identify of the object, which is returned by the [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
a = 2
print id(2), id(a)
=> 4301263008 4301263008
```

We can now answer your question:

> But how can I get the reference to one element?

You are already getting the reference to the element:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
b = a[1] 
a[1] = 3
print (b) #b is now 2, but I want the value 3 like it is in a[1]
=> 2
print id(a[1]), id(b), id(2)
=> 4301262984 4301263008 4301263008
```

A Python list always stores object references. By setting `a[1] = 3` you are in effect changing what the second list element references from id(2) to id(3). `b` continues to (correctly) hold the reference to object id(2), which is what you asked it to do.

Is there a way to achieve what you want, i.e. have `b` somehow point to the current value of `a[1]`? Two options spring to mind:

1. Store the index of the element, rather than its value:

   ```
   a = [1,2,3]
   b = []
   b = a  # reference the list
   b_i = 1  # reference the index
   a[1] = 3 # change value at index 1
   print (b[b_i]) 
   => 3
   a[1] = 4
   print (b[b_i])
   => 4
   ```
2. In the list, store objects and change the value of those objects:

   ```
   class Element(int):
       def __init__(self, value):
           self.value = value
       def __str__(self):
           return "%s" % self.value
       def __repr__(self):
           return "%s" % self.value
   a = [Element(n) for n in [1,2,3]]
   print a
   => [1, 2, 3]
   b = a[1] 
   a[1].value = 3 # don't change a[1]'s reference, change its value!
   print (b) 
   => 3
   print id(a[1]), id(b) # same object
   => 4372145648 4372145648
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a reference from a variable to a list position. Unlike C++, in Python this is not possible. The closest you can go is to create an anonymous function to reference that single list index, and assign a new value to it:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> def itemsetter(L, pos):
...     def inner(x):
...             L[pos] = x
...     return inner
... 
>>> f = itemsetter(L, 1)
>>> f
<function inner at 0x7f9e11fa35f0>
>>> f(9)
>>> L
[1, 9, 3]
```

This function resembles the way the stdlib function [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) works.

The other closest alternative is to wrap each element on the list as a referenceable mutable object. For example:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = [[x] for x in L]
>>> L2
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> A = L2[1]
>>> A[0] = 9
>>> L2
[[1], [9], [3]]
```

Instead of a list, you may create your custom class:

```
>>> class wrap:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...             self.value = value
... 
>>> L3 = [wrap(x) for x in L]
>>> L3
[<__main__.wrap instance at 0x7feca2c92ab8>, <__main__.wrap instance at 0x7feca2c92b00>, <__main__.wrap instance at 0x7feca2c92b48>]
>>> A = L3[1]
>>> A.value = 9
>>> L3[1].value
9
>>> L3[0].value
1
>>> L3[2].value
3
```

Comment: I think this could maybe help me. But I hoped to get a solution without any workaround.

Comment: @char0n another workaround is two wrap each element of the list with some kind of referenceable object. Ie, L = [1,2,3]; L2 = [[1],[2],[3]]; A = L2[1]; A[0] = 9; L2 == [[1],[9],[3]]

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` makes name `a` refering to object `b` - unlike in C / C++ **it doesn't modify object to which `a` refered before**.

```
>>> a = 2
>>> id(a)
505493912
>>> a = 3
>>> id(a)
505493928
```

Object to which `a` refered didn't changed; `a` started refering to different object.

Directly it isn't possible, but there are few workarounds, like this in the [PM 2Ring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931677/3821804).

## Yet another workaround:

```
def overload(*functions):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: functions[len(args)](*args, **kwargs)

class Ref:
    def __init__(self, new_target):
        self.target=new_target
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ref(' + repr(self.target) + ')'
    __call__=overload(None, lambda self: self.target, __init__)
```

# Usage:

```
>>> a = [Ref(1), Ref(2), Ref(3)]
>>> b = a[1]
>>> print(b)
Ref(2)
>>> a[1](3)
>>> print(b)
Ref(3)
>>> print(b())
3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you want.  Your original question involved integers, but your real problem doesn't.  Asking questions about your real situation will get better answers.

You said,

> I want to generate two lists of classes.

I think you mean objects.  Then:

> One "global" list with a user class and another list with an article class. Each article should have a "local" list of users, that are interested in this article. But this local list should only point to a subset of users of the "global" user list.

You can make a list of User objects:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.karma = 0

the_users = [User('Ned'), User('char0n'), User('Mithu')]
```

You can make a list of Article objects:

```
class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.users = []

the_articles = [Article("How to cook"), Article("Latest News")]
```

You can associate users with articles:

```
the_articles[0].users.append(the_users[0])
the_articles[1].users.append(the_users[0])
the_articles[1].users.append(the_users[1])
```

Now the articles' users lists refer to the User objects in your user list.  If you modify a user, it's visible through the article:

```
the_users[1].karma += 10
print sum(u.karma for u in the_articles[1].users)
```

Answer (score -4):

it seems like you need just redefine b = a[1] when needed, or use a[1]. As said above, integers are immutable unlike lists-I won't reiterate what others said-and so will not work. I recommend just using a[1] where needed, or reassign b = a[1] for readability of a long line.

*Answer to wrong questin below due to my misunderstanding:*

You can use the `*` operator when defining b.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = 1*a #my book says *a will work, but it creates an error in spyder when I tested it

b
>>> [1,2,3]

a[1] = 3

a
>>> [1,3,3]

b
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Source: my programming course

Comment: That is code which doesn't work and does not answer the question.

Comment: I don't see how this would help me.
At the end b contains just the values of a.

Comment: The code does work, I tested it myself before I posted it @Matthias. However I apologize as I may have misunderstood the question and answered it incorrectly.